# How to add values from a dataframe into another dataframe which is inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following `dictionary` and `dataframe`

```
cust_dict = {'ABC': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Particulars, Vch No., Outwards, Amount]
Index: [], 'BCD': Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Particulars, Vch No., Outwards, Amount]
Index: []}

df
               Date                          Particulars       Vch Type

0   2017-04-01 00:00:00                      ABC                   Sales  
1   2017-04-06 00:00:00                      BCD                   Sales   
1   2017-04-05 00:00:00                      ABC                   Sales
```

I am trying to get take `'ABC'` from `df` as the `key` and pull up the `dataframe` from the `dictionary` and add the date to the `Date` column in the `dictionary` nested `dataframe`. I have tried `.at`, `append`,`assign`.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['Particulars'])
    cust_name = row['Particulars']
    cust_dict[cust_name] = cust_dict[cust_name]['Date'].append(date)
    cust_dict[cust_name].at['Date'] = row['Date']
    # A lot of variations of .at
    if cust_name == 'ABC':
       code = 4
       cust_dict[cust_name]['Particulars'] = code
    elif cust_name == 'BCD:
       code = 5
       cust_dict[cust_name]['Particulars'] = code
```

I am not sure how to go about this or is this simply not possible?

The `df` will have multiple rows and the `particulars` column will have a company say `ABC` 4-5 times or more.

Expected output:

```
cust_dict['ABC']
   Date                          Particulars                  Vch Type

0   2017-04-01 00:00:00                 4                       Sales 
1   2017-04-05 00:00:00                 4                       Sales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way via a dictionary comprehension.

As below, I advise you use a dictionary to map Particulars instead of an `if` / `elif` construct.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'ABC', 'Sales'],
                   ['2017-04-06 00:00:00', 'BCD', 'Sales'],
                   ['2017-04-05 00:00:00', 'ABC', 'Sales']],
                  index=[0, 1, 1],
                  columns=['Date', 'Particulars', 'Vch Type'])

part_map = {'ABC': 4, 'BCD': 5}

result = {k: df[df['Particulars'] == k].assign(Particulars=part_map[k]) \
             for k in df['Particulars'].unique()}

print(result['ABC'])

#                   Date  Particulars Vch Type
# 0  2017-04-01 00:00:00            4    Sales
# 1  2017-04-05 00:00:00            4    Sales
```